# How can i display multiple texts in text container of a wizard

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp

I would like to display multiple texts in a text wizard container. I have used the setText method but it displays only the last text. Please can someone gives me a solution

Comment: The `setText` method of what? What programming language? SWT / Swing / AWT / JavaFX?

Comment: I have used  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Text;

Comment: Please be much more specific about what you are trying to do. Is this just plain text and you want to append to the existing text? Or are you trying to create a list or table of items?

Comment: ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
      // add elements to the array list
      al.add("C");
      al.add("A");
      al.add("E");
      al.add("B");
      al.add("D");
      al.add("F");

      // Use iterator to display contents of al
      System.out.print("Original contents of al: ");
      Iterator itr = al.iterator();
      while(itr.hasNext()) {
         Object element = itr.next();
         System.out.print(element + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();

Comment: i've modified  this code by replacing the System.out.println() by text.settext method it displays only the last element which is F.

Answer (score 0):

As its name suggests `Text.setText` sets the text displayed in the control and discards any previous text. So you need to construct a string containing all the data you want to show in the control and call `setText` with this. You could use a `StringBuilder` for this, something like:

```
StringBuilder buff = new StringBuilder();
for (Object element : al)
 {
   buff.append(element).append("\n");
 }
text.setText(buff.toString());
```

You will need to create the control specifying the `SWT.MULTI` style and make sure it is sized to show multiple lines.

Comment: it works but it displays an infinite series but i want is to display eqch string in an individual line(this is what i obtain"[C, A, E, B, D, F] [C, A, E, B, D, F] [C, A, E, B, D, F] [C, A, E, B, D, F] [C, A, E, B, D, F] [C, A, E, B, D, F] ").please ,could you give me an other solution

Comment: Edited to use new line separator and fix bug in element append.

Comment: i 'm using this text1 = new Text(container, SWT.BORDER| SWT.MULTI);
     text1.setText("");
 
     GridData gd = new GridData(GridData.FILL_BOTH);
     text1.setLayoutData(gd); but it gives the same previous result

Comment: Check you are using `buff.append(element).append("\n");`

Comment: yes it displays all the characters between brackets in different lines {[C, A, E, B, D, F] } but what i really want is to display each character in a line.